# Does anything extra need to be done to make my AppStore app compatible with MS inTune?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, intune

We have iOS and Android apps available for free on the AppStore and the PlayStore. A customer wants to use our app for their staff using MS Intune. I've read through the MS Intune documentation and it seems like there is nothing extra that we as developers need to do for them to use our app from the AppStore/PlayStore. Is that correct? (I know their admins will have to make it available in Intune but that's up to them. I'm asking specifically as the developer of the app.)

I want to make sure I'm not missing something since I have never actually used MS Intune myself.

Comment: There is nothing specific that you need to do if they just want to distribute the same version that is on the App Store. You can make a custom version available to the company. There is also an Intune api that you can include that makes it possible to secure data within the app linked to the device enrolment in Intune.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is this what you are talking about in regards to making the custom version to wrap the app? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-wrapper-prepare-ios

Comment: Almost. You want to avoid enterprise distribution if you can. I was referring more to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-get-started) where you can include the Intune SDK and it will only be activate when installed on an Intune managed device. App wrapping and enterprise distribution allows apps to be managed on a non-managed device (ie BYO)